# Calculating "nice" looking position for divider in JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to use `setDividerLocation` on JSplitPane to size the two panels in a "best size" fashion so that the vertical scroll bar doesn't appear in the top panel.  The split location should be just after the last of the data in the top panel.

Using `jSplitPane1.setResizeWeight(1D)` reserves too much space for the top component, resulting in empty space beneath the data.

I'm trying to get it *just right!*

[image]

Comment: You've highlighted the horizontal scroll bar; is that the one you're referring to?

Comment: To avoid confusion, I re-post the picture.

Comment: I changed the wording to make it a little more clear what you're trying to accomplish.  If this isn't what you want, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Jonathon - Very nice message re-factoring :)

Comment: Cross posted: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2134541&tstart=0 and SSCCE still not posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a `JTable` as main component in upper side of the splitpane? If so you could do like this:

```
int location = (int) table.getPreferredSize().getHeight();
location += splitPane.getDividerSize() * 2;
splitPane.setDividerLocation(location);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest avoiding moving the `JSplitPane` around while the user may want to interact with it. I can imagine it would be rather annoying to see the pane jump a few pixels before/after dragging it.

Nevertheless, you might want to take a look at obtaining the dimensions of the scrollbar, and offsetting the divider location by that amount. For instance, say you have constructed the `JTable` as follows:

```
JTable table = new JTable(myTableModel);
final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane
        .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane
        .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

You could then add a listener to the table to determine when the horizontal scroll bar is displayed, and add some offset to the `JSplitPane` as needed:

```
table.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out
            .println(scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getHeight());
    }
    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
});
```

Bear in mind that by changing the divider location, `table` will resize, causing a loop, so this construction is not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the divider location to zero then set the divider size to 0.  This will have the effect of just showing the bottom panel.  Is that what you are looking for?

```
jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(0);
jSplitPane1.setDividerSize(0);
```